# How can transform JSON to DF?

Tags: r, json

I m working with a Rstudio code, i have 450 JSON files, i have all in my workspace, with some JSON files are all rigth, but with some files like this one (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DsezCmN8_8iLNCAsLZiRnxTrwnWu6LkD/view?usp=sharing , is a 296kb json) when i try to make the field tm to dataframe i have this mistake

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

The code that i use is

```
JSONList <- rjson::fromJSON(file = "2.json", simplify = F)

DF <- as.data.frame(JSONList$tm)
```

With the files that are ok i obtain a 1 observation of 5168 variables.

How can i avoid this priblem with some files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another posibility that i think is select the rows that i need

```
    candidatos = list(
"name",
"score",
"tot_sFieldGoalsMade",
"tot_sFieldGoalsAttempted",
"tot_sTwoPointersMade",
"tot_sTwoPointersAttempted",
"tot_sThreePointersMade",
"tot_sThreePointersAttempted",
"tot_sFreeThrowsMade",
"tot_sFreeThrowsAttempted",
"tot_sReboundsDefensive",
"tot_sReboundsOffensive",
"tot_sReboundsTotal",
"tot_sAssists",
"tot_sBlocks",
"tot_sTurnovers",
"tot_sFoulsPersonal",
"tot_sPointsInThePaint",
"tot_sPointsSecondChance",
"tot_sPointsFromTurnovers",
"tot_sBenchPoints",
"tot_sPointsFastBreak",
"tot_sSteals"
)

 ListColum<-map(candidatos, function(x){
    as.data.frame(data$tm$"2"$x)
     } )
```

But R give me a list of 23 DF with no elements